# What to do when critical database initialization and/or upgrades can take a lengthy amount of time?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

For the next version of our app I need to make a REST call and pre-populate a database table when the user first installs or upgrades.  These two operations can be lengthy and numerous screens rely on the operations to be complete.

I was thinking that I could do a blocking progress dialog until the operations are finished since this would only be a one-time process.  If I did this I am not sure how best to display and dismiss the dialog.  If I do not block the UI then I would need to implement some flags and checks in the numerous screens that rely on the database operations to be complete.

What would be the best practice for doing an upgrade like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView to show the user some new features when doing stuff in the background? So you show them views with mockup data, they can play around and when you're ready, you start the real activity with all the right data.